# Catching Duplicate Upload Error within YouTube API v3

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

At this time I'm able to upload Videos to my own YouTube channel on the back-end using API V3 with OAuth 2.0 seamlessly, the need I have is to notify users when they upload the same video twice. As far as I can see YouTube API V3 does not detects this issue until upload has finished. So this means that even if a video is a duplicated one, the upload will always succeed and then the YouTube interface will show the message: "ID Duplicated Video" to the right side of video list on my channel.

How can I read this info (ID Duplicated Video) through the API in PHP so that I can be able to notify user about this duplicated upload?

Answer (score 0):

There is no interface to check if a user is uploading a duplicate video before uploading the entire file.  Presumably, YouTube performs some kind of hash on the file after the upload has completed in order to check if it is a duplicate upload.  Because the video file needs to be uploaded in its entirety for this check to happen, there is no way to check for a duplicate upload (currently) before an upload has completed.

Comment: Happily when Video is uploaded through my website the video shows message "This is a copy of a former uploaded video". So that´s what I need the user to see. Thanks for your help.